# How come this ruby thread snippet is not working?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I have a Ruby class that has a @my_threads array attribute. I do this (pseudo-code)

```
class MyClass
  @my_threads = []
  ...
  def do_something()
    %w[host1 host2].each do |h|
      cmd = %Q{ssh to $h; do_something; exit}
      t = Thread.new(cmd)
      @my_threads << t
    end
    @my_threads.each {|t| t.join}
  end

  def do_something_else()
    @my_threads.clear
    %w[host1 host2].each do |h|
      cmd = %Q{ssh to $h; do_something_else; exit}
      t = Thread.new(cmd)
      @my_threads << t
    end
    @my_threads.each {|t| t.join}
  end
end

myClass = MyClass.new
myClass.do_something
myClass.do_something_else
```

do_something behaves as expected, that is, I spawn two threads, one for host1 and another for host2, which, respectively, ssh to each host and does something and then exits.

Howerver, when do_something_else executes, it does spawn two threads, **BUT both for host2, that is, on my console output, I see the script ssh'ng to host2 twice.** I do a puts cmd and see the cmd it is correct, that is, the first one for host1 and the next for host2.

Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: If you comment out `myClass.do_something`, what do you see?

Comment: @WandMaker. Well in my real code, myClass.do_something_else depends on myClass.do_something, so I just can't comment it out. However, I even tried code where I'm using a different threads array attribute, e.g., my_threads2 in do_something_else function, to no avail.

Comment: Don't show us pseudo code unless you want a pseudo answer. By all means trim your code of irrelevant details, but what's left at the end should be valid ruby that still exhibits the problem

Comment: What is `Threads.new(cmd)`? Do you mean `Thread.new(cmd)`? The code you've posted doesn't work (with Ruby 2.2.3), can you post an example that does work?

Comment: @DavidConrad. I edited the code with Thread.new - it was a typo.

Comment: The code in the question isn’t valid (e.g. `[host1 host2]` will give a syntax error). Without seeing a real example of the issue you are facing no one will be able to help; at best we can guess.

Comment: Never retype code. You'll always blow it. Get a minimal example working on your machine and paste it here. If you can't give us a working example, we can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

I got something to work, that is, putting a sleep call as seen below. But I don't understand why? It must be a race condition between when the cmd variable is updated to when the thread is created. Is there a better solution?

```
class MyClass
  @my_threads = []
  ...
  def do_something()
    %w[host1 host2].each do |h|
      cmd = %Q{ssh to $h; do_something; exit}
      t = Thread.new(cmd)
      @my_threads << t
    end
    @my_threads.each {|t| t.join}
  end

  def do_something_else()
    @my_threads.clear
    %w[host1 host2].each do |h|
      cmd = %Q{ssh to $h; do_something_else; exit}
      t = Thread.new(cmd)
      @my_threads << t
      ######### Added sleep call ###########
      sleep 5 
    end
    @my_threads.each {|t| t.join}
  end
end

myClass = MyClass.new
myClass.do_something
myClass.do_something_else
```